# Convert a string to a list (with elements that are not strings)

Tags: python, list, converters

I have a string in the following format:

```
s = "['1', '2', '['a', 'b']']"
```

And I want to convert it to this list, where each element is not a string:

```
l = [1, 2, ['a', 'b']]
```

How can I do that if I don't know from the beginning how long each of the final elements of the list will be?

Comment: May I ask why you would want to do this?(And by the way, don't use builtin names such as `str` or `list` for variable names. Its bad practice)

Comment: at least post a well formed string

Comment: That is not a proper string in the first place

Comment: I have just corrected the string, thanks for pointing it out. I want to do that because the string is in an output file, and I need to load the informations on that file in another program.

Comment: Where is the string coming from? Also are they really all single quotes and how deep in the nesting?

Comment: No, the quotes around the square brackets are double in the file, but when I first typed them as they are I received those comments about the string not being well formed

Comment: What does the actual line in the file look like, and do you have any control over the file being produced ?

Comment: No, I have no control over the file that gives me that string. The actual string is as follows:
['29/09/2016', "['Leo', 'Jeanette', 'Eddie']", "['Eddie', 'Leo', 'Jeanette']", '[20, 10, 5]', '\n']

Comment: @Efferalgan and the irony is that  the question you linked to is also marked as a duplicate. Its a small world after...

Comment: That's not entirely true, I guess. Here, some parts of the list should be converted to floats or integers, while others remain strings or even lists?

Comment: @Efferalgan No, I didn't mean you had to change it. Its fine. higher rep users usually sort out duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

Convert small change in input then you will get get output very easily, like this,

```
In [1]: s = """['1', '2', "['a', 'b']"]"""
In [2]: print s
['1', '2', "['a', 'b']"]
In [3]: out = eval(s)
In [4]: out
Out[1]: ['1', '2', "['a', 'b']"]
In [5]: out[2] = eval(out[2])
In [6]: out
Out[2]: ['1', '2', ['a', 'b']]
```